# Backgammon like game - for which I can't find the English name

Tags: identify-this-game, backgammon

The game is very similar to backgammon, here we call it mahbusa (هو سجين, jail in Arabic).

The game is the same but

1. you start with all the stones out (in the jail/on the bar)
2. when captured, pieces are not thrown into jail, but stay "under" and can't move until the capturing piece moves

I guess this is very close to Plakoto (the difference is the first condition), but not 100% the same.

Does anyone know this game under a different name than mahbusa (هو سجين)?

Answer (score 3):

Mahbusa is the name of this Backgammon variant, and best known under this name.

Not widely used are the terms "Six-Point Backgammon" or "Short Backgammon", but I would not rely on these terms as exclusively used for Mahbusa.

Sometimes the general name Tables is used for a whole class of backgammon-like games.

For a list of backgammon variations, also see

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tables_game
- https://www.bkgm.com/variants/
- https://gambiter.com/backgammon/Tables_game.html

A personal note: I think the name of Mahbusa sounds very nice, and does not need another name.